# Getting consistent image with distributed rendering

Tags: rendering, depth-of-field

I have a homemade render farm that I cobbled together out of several retired PCs. My script splits the image into several slices, sends each slice to a node (6 slices for 6 nodes) and then combines the image in the compositor. My problem is that depth of field is inconsistent across nodes. Here's the result using the BMW test blend.
[image: bad image 1]

You can start to see noise where the depth of field kicks in. Here's the image again without output in the compositor where you can really see the effect.
[image: bad image 2]

I've tested with other blends with DOF to the same result. If I render on a single node the noise isn't there, or at least it's even across the image so it's not noticed. Any idea how I can get a consistent results across nodes?

Comment: Are some of them rendering on GPU and others on CPU?

Comment: originally yes, then I changed it to only CPU and get the same result.